# How to convert html to pdf using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, html2pdf, htmldoc

I have written html in shell script and saving that output to  output.html and i want convert that output.html to output.pdf and to output.json how to do that?

```
<table class="table table-sm">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">#</th>
<th scope="col">First</th>
<th scope="col">Last</th>
<th scope="col">Handle</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row">1</th>
<td>Mark</td>
<td>Otto</td>
<td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">2</th>
<td>Jacob</td>
<td>Thornton</td>
<td>@fat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">3</th>
<td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
<td>@twitter</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

to convert the file in PDF you may need the utility to be installed

[Follow this link to get this done](http://cyberciti.biz/open-source/html-to-pdf-freeware-linux-osx-windows-software/)

once you install the same, using the link mentioned run this

```
 html2pdf filename
```

Comment: how to use that in script